# What Inputs to provide to see a successful run of secure SslStream program

Tags: c#, security, ssl, networking, tls1.2

I am trying to gain some traction on secure socket implementation in c#. In my pursuit, I got a feeling about how TLS handshake works by going through Wikipedia and other sources.

I also thought to review some sample code and stumbled on the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

There are two programs(console applications) basically one for client and other for the server, to be able to run the program Main method requires to be fed with some arguments i.e. MachineName, and ServerCertificateName.

Please suggest how to get a hold of a certificate to be able to fulfill the certificate name field.

Comment: You need certificate file, MachineName can be anything, but you need to disable default certificate verification. I can provide to you more simple example.

Comment: Please provide one example to visualize the case, sorry I couldn't get to request earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple example with 2 threads. You can separate these threads between 2 applications.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serverThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
        server.Start();
        var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        var ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
        // certificate file with private key and password
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"rsa-4096.pfx", "hh87$-Jqo");
        ssl.AuthenticateAsServer(cert);
        ssl.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world"), 0, 11);
        ssl.Flush();
        ssl.Close();
        server.Stop();
    });

    var clientThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345);
        // last parameter disables certificate validation
        var ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, (a, b, c, d) => true);
        ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ssl, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            string recivedText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(recivedText);
        }
    });

    serverThread.Start();
    clientThread.Start();

    serverThread.Join();
    clientThread.Join();
}
```

You can download example certificate here: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/ConsoleTest/rsa-4096.pfx

Comment: Thank you Zergatul.